# How to get best result by using hyperparameter tuning and stacking regression?

Tags: python, hyperparameter-tuning

I want to use regression ML models to get the best possible R2 score. So I decided to do both hyperparameter tuning and combining models with stacking regressor. I'm wondering if I should do hyperparameter tuning for base and meta models individually and then use stacking regression or I should do hyperparameter tuning and stacking regressor at the same time as demonstrated [here](https://rasbt.github.io/mlxtend/user_guide/regressor/StackingCVRegressor/)? I want to use grid search method.